# How to implement tryCatch() in for loop using R

Tags: r

I've written R code using `for()` loop which reads some queries stored in R column of excel sheet, hits the server and saves the retrieved response in a text file. The code runs fine until the server responds with an error the loop execution stops. I tried implementing `tryCatch()` within my code but couldn't implement well.

Please help me implementing `tryCatch()` in my code which can save error in the different file and can continue the `for()` loop.

**Code:**

```
for (i in 1:R_column_len){
        R_column_data <- (file_data[[6]][i])
      a <- eval(parse(text = R_column_data))
      write.table(a,file = sprintf("C:/Results/F_Query_Prod_%s.txt", i))
    }
```

Comment: Where and how did you implement the `tryCatch`? What errors are you anticipating that you want to work around? Please edit your question with the updated code and error message(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this illustrates the general idea

```
library(futile.logger)

f <- function() {
    for (i in 1:10) {
        tryCatch({
            if (i %% 3 == 0)
                stop("my bad")
            ## normal behavior
            flog.info("i = %d", i)
        }, error = function(e) {
            ## error behavior
            flog.error("oops, i = %d: %s", i, conditionMessage(e))
        })
    }
}
```

producing output

```
> f()
INFO [2018-10-25 15:50:05] i = 1
INFO [2018-10-25 15:50:05] i = 2
ERROR [2018-10-25 15:50:05] oops, i = 3: my bad
INFO [2018-10-25 15:50:05] i = 4
INFO [2018-10-25 15:50:05] i = 5
ERROR [2018-10-25 15:50:05] oops, i = 6: my bad
INFO [2018-10-25 15:50:05] i = 7
INFO [2018-10-25 15:50:05] i = 8
ERROR [2018-10-25 15:50:05] oops, i = 9: my bad
INFO [2018-10-25 15:50:05] i = 10
```

Use features of futile.logger to append to file rather than the console, and to record only errors

```
fl <- tempfile()
flog.appender(appender.file(fl))
flog.threshold(ERROR)
f()
```

the result is

```
> readLines(fl)
[1] "ERROR [2018-10-26 06:28:37] oops, i = 3: my bad"
[2] "ERROR [2018-10-26 06:28:37] oops, i = 6: my bad"
[3] "ERROR [2018-10-26 06:28:37] oops, i = 9: my bad"
```

Comment: Thanks! `futile.logger` example what you have mentioned really helped me to proceed further. Now I'm able to handle the errors occurred while execution and proceeding to the next query. But the errors which are being logged are not being appended. Only one error is being saved in a file.

Check the codes in next comment.

Comment: `Prod.Execution <- function(){
  
  for (i in 14:17){
   
    tryCatch({
      F.SetConfigurationItem(F.ConfigOptions.UseBeta, FALSE)
      R_column_data <- (file_data[[6]][i])
      a <- eval(parse(text = R_column_data))
      write.table(a,file = sprintf("C:/Users/squraishi/Desktop/OnDemand/R/R_ExtractDataSnapshot/ErrorTest/F_Query_Prod_%s.txt", i))
      
  },error = function(e){
      
      flog.error(conditionMessage(e))
     write(conditionMessage(e),file = sprintf("C:/ErrorFile.txt", append=TRUE))
    })
  }
}
invisible(flog.threshold(INFO))
Prod.Execution()`

Comment: edit your original question rather than making elaborate additions to the comments. Write your code so that I and others can 'copy paste' and reproduce, e.g., we do not have a user 'squrishi' corresponding file to read from.

Comment: (for the error condition, `append=TRUE` is not in the correct location, it is applied to `sprintf()` rather than `write()`).

Comment: Got it, Thanks!
the code is working fine for me now. I have removed `sprintf()` function.